# Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-installer, installation

I am trying to install windows 8 on my PC (it has all the minimum requirements) 
When I insert the CD, it starts to boot normally from it, but then i get an error:

Your PC needs to restart.
Please hold down the power button.

```
Error Code: 0x0000005D
Parameters:
0x030F0401
0x756E6547
0x49656E69
0x6C65746E
```

I have tried to restart the computer but I get that error again.
I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: [0x5D indicates an unsupported processor.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 "Bug Check 0x5D: UNSUPPORTED_PROCESSOR (Windows Debuggers)") Are you sure your processor has the features required for Windows 8? [PAE, NX, and the SSE2 instruction set are required.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/what-is-pae-nx-sse2 "What are PAE, NX, and SSE2? - Windows Help")

Comment: it doesn't have PAE, but i didn't think about that when I tried to install it :)
now i'm still using the PC with windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message tell that CPU doesn't support the required CPU features like SSE2, PAE and NX-Bit.

May be [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/27098-unable-to-install-windows-8-error-code-0x0000005d#solution) can help you:-

> Unlike Windows Vista and 7, Windows 8 (as from build 8400) is not
> compatible with all models of the Pentium 4 processor.
>
> This is due to the fact that Windows 8 requires a processor compatible
> with the following functions: SSE2, PAE and NX bit. All Pentium 4 are
> compatible with SSE2 and EAP: the problem may come from the NX bit.
>
> - First, make sure your Pentium 4 model supports the NX bit: for    sockets 423 or 478 processors, then it won't work (in most cases).
> - For sockets 775 processors, it can be compatible. If the CPU supports NX-bit, you    can install Windows 8 32-bit or 64-bit (it
>   depends on the models!).
> - Also make sure that NX bit is not disabled in the BIOS (if present).

Also check this:- **[PAE/NX/SSE2 Support Requirement Guide for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh975398.aspx)**

Comment: the only thing i can change in the bios is:
CPU Host frequency which is set to automatic,
Boot Filure Guard - Enabled
Spread Spectrum - Auto
CPU Themal Throttling - enabled
Max CPUD Value limit - disabled

besides, we are talking about an about 8 years old intel celeron CPU , single core, 2,53GHz

Comment: @user2700896 So what did you expect?

Comment: i expected it at least to run somehow, it says that the minimum requirement is 1GHz of CPU...